# Best way to pass a list of key/value pairs in URI query parameter

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, restful-url, csv, query-string

What's the best method to pass a set of key/value pairs via a HTTP request?

As an example, say, I need to send a sort command to a RESTful service. I need to specify a list of properties to sort by and the order that I wish to sort each of them by e.g. sort **Title** by **ascending** order and then **Name** by **descending** order, and so forth for each property.

This is how I am currently building the request:

&sort=Title:ASC,Name:DESC

So, I am delimiting by ":" and then by ",". Is this the best method, in terms of conformance to the RESTful guidelines to pass such data pairs?

Thanks,
F.

Answer (score 0):

depending on the language being used there are multiple methods.

Usually using encode(jsonstring) is the best way, but that also depends on security settings and such ...